# Django: is this data migration going to blow the server memory?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to migrate the data from an old table to a new table and I'm not sure what the best way would be.

There's the simple solution of creating every object:

```py
def migrate_data(apps, schema_editor):
    UserPreferences = apps.get_model("authentication", "UserPreferences")
    UserPreferencesOld = apps.get_model("authentication", "UserPreferencesOld")

    for user_preferences_old in UserPreferencesOld.objects.all():
        user_preferences = UserPreferences(
            date_modified=user_preferences_old.date_modified,
            email_notifications=user_preferences_old.email_notifications,
            show_message_deadline_summary=(
                user_preferences_old.show_message_deadline_summary
            ),
            user=user_preferences_old.user,
        )
        user_preferences.save()
```

And the bulk create solution:

```py
def migrate_data(apps, schema_editor):
    UserPreferences = apps.get_model("authentication", "UserPreferences")
    UserPreferencesOld = apps.get_model("authentication", "UserPreferencesOld")

    UserPreferences.objects.bulk_create(
        [
            UserPreferences(
                date_modified=user_preferences_old.date_modified,
                email_notifications=user_preferences_old.email_notifications,
                show_message_deadline_summary=(
                    user_preferences_old.show_message_deadline_summary
                ),
                user=user_preferences_old.user,
            )
            for user_preferences_old in UserPreferencesOld.objects.all()
        ]
    )
```

The table I need to migrate has tens of thousands of entries and I'm afraid that the first option will take forever, making tens of thousands of requests to the database, while the second option will blow the memory on the server.

Any suggestions on what would be the better option? Thanks!

Comment: As a middle term I would go for bulk but use pages instead of `.all()`

Comment: Another option would be to write a SQL query and run it directly, without pulling anything to the Python side.

Answer (score 0):

1) Keep in mind that "bulk_create" won't trigger any signals.

2) I'd rather execute your code in batches. You could use `iterator` for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#iterator

3) If you are worried that this will blow up anything in your server there's nothing wrong on waiting a second or two after you iterated over a big batch.

4) Migrations are atomic by default
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/writing-migrations/

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions from gecko and Marcelo, this is what I did in the end and it works perfectly.

```py
PAGE_SIZE_CREATE = 500

def migrate_data(apps, schema_editor):
    UserPreferences = apps.get_model("authentication", "UserPreferences")
    UserPreferencesOld = apps.get_model("authentication", "UserPreferencesOld")

    paginator = Paginator(UserPreferencesOld.objects.all(), PAGE_SIZE_CREATE)

    for p in paginator.page_range:
        UserPreferences.objects.bulk_create(
            [
                UserPreferences(
                    date_created=user_prefs_old.date_modified,
                    date_modified=user_prefs_old.date_modified,
                    email_notifications=user_prefs_old.email_notifications,
                    show_message_deadline_summary=(
                        user_prefs_old.show_message_deadline_summary
                    ),
                    user=user_prefs_old.user,
                )
                for user_prefs_old in paginator.page(p)
            ]
        )
```